# What are some good introductory books to QFT?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, quantum-field-theory

What are some good introductory books to the mathematics of quantum field theory? Basically talks about how exactly it differs from 1st quantisation quantum mechanics.

Comment: I haven't read it, but I bet Folland's book on Quantum Field Theory is good: https://www.amazon.com/Quantum-Theory-Mathematical-Surveys-Monographs/dp/0821847058